# How can I add a line break to a list of lists?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function in python, which reads csv files and returns them nicely formatted. The input files are just standard csv files. Where each line represents a person. The output format should look like:

```
[
    ("Age", "Gender", "Weight (kg)", "Height (cm)"),
    ("28", "Female", "58", "168"),
    ("33", "Male", "", "188")
]
```

The thing is just don't know how I can do this. I know that I can loop through every element in my list of lists and print it, but I would like to return them as above. The only format I manage to end up with looks like:

```
[('Age', 'Gender', 'Weight (kg)', 'Height (cm)'), ('28', 'Female', '58', '168'), ('33', 'Male', '', '188')]
```

In case anyone need to see my code(I guess it's not nicely coded at all but I'm learning):

```
def read_csv(path):
    newlist = []
    with open("example.csv", "r") as f:
        nr_of_lines = 0
        for line in f.readlines():
            counter = 0
            nr_of_lines += 1
            while "," in line:   
                idx = line.find(",")
                entry = line[0:idx]
                newlist.append(entry)
                line = line[idx+1:]
                counter += 1
                if "," not in line: 
                    idx2 = line.find("\n")
                    newlist.append(line[:idx2])

    nr_elements_per_line = int(len(newlist)/nr_of_lines)
    tuple_list = []
    for i in range(nr_of_lines):
        tuple_list.append(tuple(newlist[nr_elements_per_line*i:nr_elements_per_line+i*nr_elements_per_line]))
        
    return tuple_list
print(read_csv("example.csv"))
```

Comment: did you try using pprint? `from pprint import pprint` -  `pprint(read_csv("example.csv"))`  - this will probably not be your exact format but should help printing nicely.

Comment: You want the output to be a single string that looks like that? Not a python list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pprint` module for slightly better printing, or print all yourself:

```
data = [('Age', 'Gender', 'Weight (kg)', 'Height (cm)'), 
        ('28', 'Female', '58', '168'), 
        ('33', 'Male', '', '188')]

print('[')
for inner in data:
    print(f"\t{inner}")
print(']')
```

Output:

```
[
    ('Age', 'Gender', 'Weight (kg)', 'Height (cm)')
    ('28', 'Female', '58', '168')
    ('33', 'Male', '', '188')
]
```

---

With `pprint`:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
[('Age', 'Gender', 'Weight (kg)', 'Height (cm)'),
 ('28', 'Female', '58', '168'),
 ('33', 'Male', '', '188')]
```

Comment: Thanks this was just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can use pprint as shown above. There is a pretty nice library called as tabulate that can be used to display tabular data as shown below.

```
>>> from tabulate import tabulate
>>> data = [('Age', 'Gender', 'Weight (kg)', 'Height (cm)'), ('28', 'Female', '58', '168'), ('33', 'Male', '', '188')]
>>> print(tabulate(data[1:], headers=data[0]))
  Age  Gender    Weight (kg)      Height (cm)
-----  --------  -------------  -------------
   28  Female    58                       168
   33  Male                               188
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't look for this but this will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Python favors single quotes when writing the REPR (representation) of strings. But you can write your own by emitting the string without quotes and wrapping them yourself.

```
def my_pformat(table):
    tupstr = [", ".join(f'"{s}"' for s in tup) for tup in table]
    tupline = [f"    ({tup})" for tup in tupstr]
    return "\n".join(["["] + tupline + ["]"])

table = [('Age', 'Gender', 'Weight (kg)', 'Height (cm)'), 
        ('28', 'Female', '58', '168'), 
        ('33', 'Male', '', '188')]

print(my_pformat(table))
```

Result

```
[
    ("Age", "Gender", "Weight (kg)", "Height (cm)")
    ("28", "Female", "58", "168")
    ("33", "Male", "", "188")
]
```

Comment: I didn't actually refer to the single/double quotes but thanks nonetheless!